# How to get date object prior 3 months from current date in Typescript

Tags: typescript, date

I am trying to get the date object before 3 months from current date like this.

```
toDate = new Date();
fromDate  = this.toDate.getMonth() - 3;
```

But `fromDate` is coming as just a number. Every time i want to get the date before 3 months from current date. But this shows only a option like this.

```
this.fromDate = (this.toDate.getMonth() - 3).toLocaleString()
```

Is it possible to get the date object before 3 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a number from `getMonth` is because it returns the integer value, or "index", of a month. January is 0, December is 11. [See the `getMonth` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) for more details.

To get a new Date 3 months in the past, you should use the built in Date [`setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) function.

```js
function monthsBackFrom(date: Date, n: number): Date {
  // Create a new date so the original is not modified
  const result = new Date(date);

  // Careful, setMonth modifies the date object in place
  result.setMonth(result.getMonth() - n); // Set to n months back from current
  return result;
}

const now = new Date();
const threeMonthsBack: Date = monthsBackFrom(now, 3);

console.log(now.toString()) // Current date and time
console.log(threeMonthsBack.toString()); // Date three months back, same time
```

Note that `setMonth` **modifies your date in place.** It does not create a new one. You will most likely need to create a new Date object when setting *fromDate* so your *toDate* is not affected.

`setMonth` also supports negatives and values greater than 12. Setting the month to `-1` will set the date to **December of the previous year**. Setting the month to 12 will set the date to *January of the next year**. Day and time information remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i can help

```
toDate = new Date();
month = toDate.getMonth() -3;
newDate = new Date(toDate.setMonth(month));
```

Comment: what happen if years are different when i am deducting 3 months like `toDate`  year - 2017 & `fromDate`   year - 2016

Comment: It can, you can test

Comment: toDate = new Date();
->> Wed Jan 06 2021 09:55:54 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
newDate = new Date(toDate.setMonth(toDate.getMonth()-3));
-->> Tue Oct 06 2020 09:58:13 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
1/2021 -> 10/2020